# Cannot find Registry Setting for Office Shared Templates

Tags: group-policy, templates, microsoft-office

We have our Templates for Office 2003 located in a shared location \servername\Templates$
This is also the location of our Word Startup Folder. Both settings are set in a User Group Policy.
This has been working for Word forever. Now we have a company who is making a Powerpoint template for us. They are trying to refer to the network location by reading the registry setting SharedTemplates that is supposed to be located at

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Common\General

The problem is that there is no such registry entry there. But Word is working. 
So I am trying to find out how Word knows the network location, so that the Powerpoint template can get the same location.
I really do not want to hard code the location into the Powerpoint Addin.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regshot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/) to find defferences in registry with enabled setting in group policy and with disabled one.

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing the template location setting on a sacrificial sample computer to a string of gibberish, and then searching the registry for that same string.